.NET MAUI C# Fragment ID Not Found
I have an .NET MAUI project. I made a login page and I tried to login I take:
Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'No view found for id 0x7f080147 (com.companyname.sportakip:id/navigationlayout_toptabs) for fragment ViewFragment{8c14672} (fad55514-6fd6-44c4-b996-91651de58922 id=0x7f080147)'

error.
I tried to add a fragment that navigationlayout_toptabs have ID in navigationlayout.xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigationlayout_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/navigationlayout_toptabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/navigationlayout_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/navigationlayout_bottomtabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


But it doesn't work.
Here is my xaml code that I'm getting error:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SporTakip"
             x:Class="SporTakip.AnaSayfa2"
             Title="AnaSayfa2">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Gray" VerticalOptions="Center" Orientation="Vertical" Padding="10,15,15,10" Spacing="20"  >





            <Frame BackgroundColor="Red" Padding="20" HasShadow="True"  VerticalOptions="End">
                <Label Text="Hoşgeldiniz!  Uygulamayı kullanmak için önce giriş yapın" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                           FontAttributes="Italic" FontSize="Title" TextColor="White" />

            </Frame>

            <Entry x:Name="kullaniciAdiEntry" Placeholder="Kullanıcı Adı" PlaceholderColor="Black"
                       VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black" 
Keyboard="Text"/>
            <Entry x:Name="sifreEntry" Placeholder="Şifre"
                       PlaceholderColor="Black" TextColor="Black"
IsPassword="True"/>

            <Button x:Name="btnGirisYap" Text="Giriş Yap"  
 BackgroundColor="Black"
 TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center"  CornerRadius="15" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="1"
 Clicked="btnGirisYap_Clicked" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="300" TranslationY="50"  />
            <Button x:Name="btnKayit" Text="Kayıt Ol"  
 BackgroundColor="Black"
 TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" CornerRadius="15" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="1"
 Clicked="btnKayit_Clicked"  HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="300" TranslationY="60" />

            <Button x:Name="btnAdmin" Text="Admin Giriş" 
BackgroundColor="Black"
TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" CornerRadius="15" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="1"
Clicked="btnAdmin_Clicked"  HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="300" TranslationY="70" />

            <ListView Grid.Row="3" x:Name="myListView" HasUnevenRows="True" Footer="">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto, Auto">
                                <Label Text="{Binding ID}" />
                                <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Isim}" TextColor="Black"/>
                                <Label Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Soyisim}" TextColor="Black"/>
                                <Label Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding DogumTarihi}" TextColor="Black"/>
                                <Label Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding Cinsiyet}" TextColor="Black"/>
                                <Label Grid.Row="5" Text="{Binding Telefon}" TextColor="Black"/>

                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>


            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>

And this is the xaml.cs code:
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
namespace SporTakip;

public partial class AnaSayfa2 : ContentPage
{
    public string? KullaniciAdi { get; set; }
    public AnaSayfa2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        kullaniciAdiEntry.Text = kullanici;
        sifreEntry.Text = sifre;


        kullaniciAdiEntry.Text = KullaniciAdi;
    }
    SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source= 192.168.1.152;Initial Catalog=SporTakipUygulamasiDB; User Id= mehmet; Password= mehmettemhem12345;TrustServerCertificate=True; ");

    private async void btnKayit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new KayitEkrani());
    }
    string kullanici = "";
    string sifre = "";
    private void btnGirisYap_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        try
        {
            bool isKullaniciAdiEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(kullaniciAdiEntry.Text);
            bool isSifreEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sifreEntry.Text);
            if (isKullaniciAdiEmpty || isSifreEmpty)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Hata", "Kullanıcı adı veya şifre boş kalmamalıdır!", "Tamam");

                return;
            }

            baglanti.Open();
            SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("Select KULLANICIADI, SIFRE From TBLUYEKAYIT where KULLANICIADI=@kullanici AND SIFRE=@sifre", baglanti);
            komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kullanici", kullaniciAdiEntry.Text);
            komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sifre", sifreEntry.Text);
            komut.ExecuteNonQuery();



            SqlDataReader dr = komut.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
#pragma warning disable CS8601 // Olası null başvuru ataması.
                    kullanici = dr["KULLANICIADI"].ToString();
#pragma warning restore CS8601 // Olası null başvuru ataması.
#pragma warning disable CS8601 // Olası null başvuru ataması.
                    sifre = dr["SIFRE"].ToString();
#pragma warning restore CS8601 // Olası null başvuru ataması.


                }
            }


            if (kullaniciAdiEntry.Text != kullanici || sifreEntry.Text != sifre)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Hata", "Kullanıcı adı veya şifre yanlış", "Tamam");

            }
            else
            {

                Navigation.PushAsync(new AnaMenu(kullaniciAdiEntry.Text, sifreEntry.Text));


            }





        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            DisplayAlert("Hata", "Bir hata oluştu" + ex.Message, "Tamam");
        }
        finally
        {
            baglanti.Close();
        }



    }

    private async void btnAdmin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        await Navigation.PushAsync(new AdminGiris());


    }
}

When I clicked button named 'btnGirisYap' and when I clicked button named 'btnKayit' Im getting this error. But when I clicked button named 'btnAdmin' I'm not getting error.

How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?

I'm navigating another page when I clicked button 'btnGirisYap' and 'btnKayit'. I was using Xamarin to make my application but I created new .NET MAUI project and added my codes there. After this I started to get this error.

What exactly do you want to achieve? If you want to access the android platform APIs, you can try to Invoke platform code to achieve this.

Are you using .NET Android Native into a .NET MAUI app?

I fixed the problem. I was using TabbedPage in my xaml code. I turned it to ContentPage and got rid of from problem. Thank you for your helps.
